# How Do I Solve This BSCScan Verification Error?

Tags: token, bscscan

I created my token on BSC and I am currently trying to verify the code on BSCScan:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20 ("Token", "TKN"){
        _mint(msg.sender,initialSupply);
    }
}
```

But, when I try to verify, this error pops out:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaHzZ.png)